# Not able to download Postgresql 9.6.1 version on raspberry pi 3 (OS : Debian Jessie)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, raspberry-pi3, postgresql-9.6, debian-jessie

I specifically need this version to make it compatible with heroku app psql version. If the versions don't match, I cannot pull the database from heroku app to a local machine.

When I execute,

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

Error I get is:

> pg_dump: server version: 9.6.1; pg_dump version: 9.4.2
>   pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

However, when I try to install 9.6 version on my raspberry pi 3,
When I execute

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

the error I get is:

> E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.6
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.6'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the jessie-backports repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. E.g.

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Then, you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6`. The jessie-backports suite should be available from most mirrors, so you can choose whatever mirror you pull the other suites from.